# MySQL NDB auto_increment backfilling

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-cluster

We had standalone DB with `innodb` engine, on it `auto_increment was working perfectly giving sequential numbers 1,2,3,4,5

But when we moved to `NDB` Cluster, it started backfilling available numbers. for example if i have

```
12,13,14,16,17
```

if i add new entry it will take place `15` it suppose to add entry in `18`

is there any configuration this there? which we missed?

## UPDATE

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`   output is following

```
 in_invoices | CREATE TABLE `in_invoices` (
      `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      ...
      ...
      ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=2051 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: It sounds like the behavior you're seeing is that it **is** backfilling.

Comment: yes its just grabbing whatever available number in past.

Comment: But your question says "When we moved to NDB Cluster it is **not** backfilling numbers".

Comment: What does it say in the `AUTO_INCREMENT=` field when you do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry it was typo i have remove **not** keyword, thanks correction

Comment: I have updated my question with table output

Comment: You left out the part I asked for. At the end it should say `ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER AUTO_INCREMENT=something`

Comment: @Barmar sorry just updated that in question

Comment: And when you insert a new row, it doesn't give it `invoice_id = 2051`, it fills in a gap instead?

Comment: Yes, whatever available or we deleted past.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `AUTO_INCREMENT` says that they will be distinct values, it says nothing about backfilling or not, nor when gaps are generated.  Do not depend on such.